# Fast way for One Hot Encoding with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, one-hot-encoding

In my project, I need to make oneHotEncode for millions of DNA sequences for ~100 time(in total, billions of times of similar sequences). So an effiect way will be very improtant for me.

Bellow is my code, which takes 4.5s for 10K sequences.

```py
import numpy as np
import os,sys,time

def dna2onehot(dnaSeq):
    seqLen = len(dnaSeq)
    dnaSeq = dnaSeq.upper()

    # initialize the matrix to seqlen x 4
    seqMatrix = np.zeros((seqLen,4))
    # change the value to matrix
    for i in range(0,seqLen):
            if dnaSeq[i] == 'A':
                    seqMatrix[i,0] = 1
            if dnaSeq[i] == 'C':
                    seqMatrix[i,1] = 1
            if dnaSeq[i] == 'G':
                    seqMatrix[i,2] = 1
            if dnaSeq[i] == 'T':
                    seqMatrix[i,3] = 1
    ret = np.array(seqMatrix.flat)
    return ret
#

sequence = "TCTGAGTCCCAATACACAAGAGGTTCCCTCACCTGTTCTGGTGTCAGACCCTCCCAGATGATCACCTCTCCTATGGCGGGGAAGGTGCCTGGATGTCTAAAGCCTGAAATGGGGATCTATCCCAGAAGCTGTGTAGCTTCTGCCTGTCCCAGAAGCTGTGTTGTTTCTGTATTCAGCTTGCTCACCCTCCGCAGTCCATTGATCTGCACAGACTGTTCTCAGATGGACTCGTGAGACAAGATGGCTCCTTCACCTGCTCTGGGGATCAGAACCCTCCCAGGTGGCCACCTCTCCTGTGGTGGGGAAGGTACCTGGAAGTCTTCAGCCCAAAACAGGGCCTGTCCCAGAAGCTGTGTCTCTTCTGCCTATCCCAGAAGCTGTATTGCTTCTGCTGTCCACTTGCTCACCCTCTGCAGTCTGCATGCTGATCTGCGCAGACTGTTCTCAGAGGGATCTGGCAGACAAGTTGGCTCCCTCACCTGCTCTGGGGCGGGGGGGGGGGGTTCAGAGCCCTCCTGGGCAGCCACCTCTCCTCTAGCAGAGAAGGTGCTGGGATGTCTTGAGCAGGAAACGGGGTATGTCCCAGAAGCTGTCTTGCTTCTGCAATCCACATGCTCAGCCTCTGCAGTCTGTGAGCTAATCTGGGCAGTCTGGTCTCAGGGGACTCTGGAGACAAGATGGCTCCCTCACCTGCTCTGGGGGTCAAAGCCCTCCTTGGCAGCCACCTTTTTCAGGCGGAGAAGGTGCCCGGATGTCTGGAGCCTGAAACAGGGGTATGTCCCAGACACTGTGTAGCTTCTGCCTGCCCCAGAAGATGTGTCACTTCCTCAGTCTGCTTGTTCACCCTCCACAGTCTGCAAGCTGATCTGCACAGACTGGTCTCAGAGGGACCTAGAAGACAAGATCAAGAAAAGTCTTATAGGTATAATGAATCAAGCAGAAAATGAAACATCAGAAGCTTAAGATAAAATACAGGATCTAGTCCAAATTAGCAAGAAGTA"

count = 10000
datalist = []
t1 = time.time()
for k in range(count):
    datalist.append(dna2onehot(sequence))
#
t2 = time.time()
print("time cost:",t2-t1)
```

Do you have any suggestion to reduce the time with python (My whole project was based on python)?

Comment: If you were to just wrap your function with the JIT compiler from `numba`, it would likely be much faster without any changes. Intro tutorial: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OneHotEncoder` from scikit-learn.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# create the encoder object
encoder = OneHotEncoder()

sequence = 'TCTGAGTCCCAATACACAAGAGGTTCCCTCACCTGTTCTGGTGTCAGACCCTCCCAGATGATCACCTCTCCTATGGCG'
sequence += 'GGGAAGGTGCCTGGATGTCTAAAGCCTGAAATGGGGATCTATCCCAGAAGCTGTGTAGCTTCTGCCTGTCCCAGAAGC'
sequence += 'TGTGTTGTTTCTGTATTCAGCTTGCTCACCCTCCGCAGTCCATTGATCTGCACAGACTGTTCTCAGATGGACTCGTGA'
sequence += 'GACAAGATGGCTCCTTCACCTGCTCTGGGGATCAGAACCCTCCCAGGTGGCCACCTCTCCTGTGGTGGGGAAGGTACC'
sequence += 'TGGAAGTCTTCAGCCCAAAACAGGGCCTGTCCCAGAAGCTGTGTCTCTTCTGCCTATCCCAGAAGCTGTATTGCTTCT'
sequence += 'GCTGTCCACTTGCTCACCCTCTGCAGTCTGCATGCTGATCTGCGCAGACTGTTCTCAGAGGGATCTGGCAGACAAGTT'
sequence += 'GGCTCCCTCACCTGCTCTGGGGCGGGGGGGGGGGGTTCAGAGCCCTCCTGGGCAGCCACCTCTCCTCTAGCAGAGAAG'
sequence += 'GTGCTGGGATGTCTTGAGCAGGAAACGGGGTATGTCCCAGAAGCTGTCTTGCTTCTGCAATCCACATGCTCAGCCTCT'
sequence += 'GCAGTCTGTGAGCTAATCTGGGCAGTCTGGTCTCAGGGGACTCTGGAGACAAGATGGCTCCCTCACCTGCTCTGGGGG'
sequence += 'TCAAAGCCCTCCTTGGCAGCCACCTTTTTCAGGCGGAGAAGGTGCCCGGATGTCTGGAGCCTGAAACAGGGGTATGTC'
sequence += 'CCAGACACTGTGTAGCTTCTGCCTGCCCCAGAAGATGTGTCACTTCCTCAGTCTGCTTGTTCACCCTCCACAGTCTGC'
sequence += 'AAGCTGATCTGCACAGACTGGTCTCAGAGGGACCTAGAAGACAAGATCAAGAAAAGTCTTATAGGTATAATGAATCAA'
sequence += 'GCAGAAAATGAAACATCAGAAGCTTAAGATAAAATACAGGATCTAGTCCAAATTAGCAAGAAGTA'

# transform sequence to a Nx1 array, pass through fit/transform operation
seq_arr = np.array(list(sequence)).reshape(-1, 1)
seq_1hot = encoder.fit_transform(seq_arr).toarray()

seq_1hot
# returns:
array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

You can see which letters correspond to which column by looking at:

```py
encoder.categories_
# returns:
[array(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'], dtype='<U1')]
```

So in this case they are in alphabetic order.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I just tested in this way, it taked 9.6 secs to process 10K sequences

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly faster (and simpler) approach:

```
sequence = "TCTGAGTCCCAATACACAAGAGGTTCCCTCACCTGTTCTGGTGTCAGACCCTCCCAGATGATCACCTCTCCTATGGCGGGGAAGGTGCCTGGATGTCTAAAGCCTGAAATGGGGATCTATCCCAGAAGCTGTGTAGCTTCTGCCTGTCCCAGAAGCTGTGTTGTTTCTGTATTCAGCTTGCTCACCCTCCGCAGTCCATTGATCTGCACAGACTGTTCTCAGATGGACTCGTGAGACAAGATGGCTCCTTCACCTGCTCTGGGGATCAGAACCCTCCCAGGTGGCCACCTCTCCTGTGGTGGGGAAGGTACCTGGAAGTCTTCAGCCCAAAACAGGGCCTGTCCCAGAAGCTGTGTCTCTTCTGCCTATCCCAGAAGCTGTATTGCTTCTGCTGTCCACTTGCTCACCCTCTGCAGTCTGCATGCTGATCTGCGCAGACTGTTCTCAGAGGGATCTGGCAGACAAGTTGGCTCCCTCACCTGCTCTGGGGCGGGGGGGGGGGGTTCAGAGCCCTCCTGGGCAGCCACCTCTCCTCTAGCAGAGAAGGTGCTGGGATGTCTTGAGCAGGAAACGGGGTATGTCCCAGAAGCTGTCTTGCTTCTGCAATCCACATGCTCAGCCTCTGCAGTCTGTGAGCTAATCTGGGCAGTCTGGTCTCAGGGGACTCTGGAGACAAGATGGCTCCCTCACCTGCTCTGGGGGTCAAAGCCCTCCTTGGCAGCCACCTTTTTCAGGCGGAGAAGGTGCCCGGATGTCTGGAGCCTGAAACAGGGGTATGTCCCAGACACTGTGTAGCTTCTGCCTGCCCCAGAAGATGTGTCACTTCCTCAGTCTGCTTGTTCACCCTCCACAGTCTGCAAGCTGATCTGCACAGACTGGTCTCAGAGGGACCTAGAAGACAAGATCAAGAAAAGTCTTATAGGTATAATGAATCAAGCAGAAAATGAAACATCAGAAGCTTAAGATAAAATACAGGATCTAGTCCAAATTAGCAAGAAGTA"

sequence_array = [sequence] * 10000

ntdict = {'A' : [1,0,0,0],
          'G' : [0,1,0,0],
          'C' : [0,0,1,0],            
          'T' : [0,0,0,1]}

onehot = [[ntdict [s] for s in list (seq)] for seq in sequence_array]
```